# Meteorjs Integration with ChakraUI + React Router

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, meteor-react, chakra-ui

TLDR, I got an error when integrating between those 3. But when I use Meteor with ChakraUI, it works nicely. But when I add react router, it throw this error

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

So in Meteor, I wrap the app in **client/main.jsx** with the ChakraUI provider and Browser Router. Chakra need to wrap the app in their provider base on [their docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/getting-started#setup-provider).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { App } from '/imports/ui/App';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { BrowserRouter  } from 'react-router-dom'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
  <ChakraProvider>
    <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={'dark'} />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ChakraProvider>,
    document.getElementById('react-target'));
});
```

Then in **imports/ui/App.jsx** I put react route switch to render the page. Before that, I put Home.jsx code inside it.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {Home} from './pages/Home'


export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

So is there any wrong way in my code to "wrap" the apps?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. in App.jsx you export App as default, so you should import it in main.jsx without curly braces
2. you import App.jsx from `/imports/ui/App` but you write that it's located in `imports/App.jsx`-> make sure the import is correct, that could be the problem here
3. not sure why you import `BrowserRouter as Router` in App.jsx, don't think this should lead to your error (because it's not used in the code snippet you post) - but just to be sure, it shouldn't be used anywhere else in App.jsx if it's already in main.jsx

EDIT: what solved it was the above, mainly number 1, plus another wrong import in `App.jsx` of the same sort (exported as default but imported destructuring style)

Comment: 1. When do without a curly brace, the error log seems longer because react-router-dom.

2. Updated, my app is in imports/ui

3. Already delete that, still have same error

Comment: can you share your repo?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this locally in an app I have using Meteor and React's Router: when I export default App and import it with curly braces in main.jsx, I get the exact error you do. I suggest you follow point 1 I posted and then you share the next error you get @David_Try_Everything

Comment: this is my repo https://github.com/ashlite/back-chamber

And I tried to copy paste the react router basic routing in quick start to my App.jsx, with the above main jsx setting. It still throw an error

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
    in App
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in ColorModeProvider (created by ChakraProvider)
    in ThemeProvider (created by ChakraProvider)
    in ChakraProvider

Comment: same issue as for importing App: if you export default Home in `Home.jsx` you have to import it without {} in `App.jsx`. Got your app running after applying what I mentioned above, plus:
4. change line 3 in `App.js` to `import Home from './pages/Home'`

Comment: You're very welcome! Your App already looks quite nice   Have fun with Meteor, it's great!